# How do we calculate the proposed limit when $\theta\to 0^{+}$ and when $\theta\to 1^{-}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

So here it is the function which I am interested in:
\begin{align*}
f(\theta) = \frac{6}{\theta^{2}}\left[-5\theta + (1+3\theta)\ln(1-\theta) + (3+\theta)\sqrt{\theta}\ln\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\theta}}{1-\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\right]
\end{align*}

wher $\theta\in(0,1)$.

I would like to know how to calculate its limit when $\theta\to 0^{+}$ and when $\theta\to 1^{-}$.

One possible approach consists in applying the L'Hôpital rule when $\theta$ approaches $0$.

But isn't there any other "clever" way to calculate it?

Still, it remains to solve the problem when $\theta\to 1^{-}$.

This is part of my research project. Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: How about using the series expansion of ln(1+x). I think it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that composition of Taylor series is convenient (working one piece at the time). If you have numerator and denominator present, work each of them separately.

Your case
\begin{align*}
f(\theta) = \frac{6}{\theta^{2}}\left[-5\theta + (1+3\theta)\log(1-\theta) + (3+\theta)\sqrt{\theta}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\theta}}{1-\sqrt{\theta}}\right)\right]
\end{align*} is rather simple since around $\theta=0$ since you need to use
$$\log(1-\theta)=-\theta -\frac{\theta ^2}{2}-\frac{\theta ^3}{3}-\frac{\theta ^4}{4}+O\left(\theta^5\right)$$ For the most delicate piece, I should first use $\theta=x^2$
$$A=\sqrt{\theta}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{\theta}}{1-\sqrt{\theta}}\right)=x \log \left(\frac{x+1}{1-x}\right)=x \left(2 x+\frac{2 x^3}{3}+\frac{2 x^5}{5}+\frac{2 x^7}{7}+O\left(x^9\right) \right)$$
$$A=2 x^2+\frac{2 x^4}{3}+\frac{2 x^6}{5}+\frac{2 x^8}{7}+O\left(x^{10}\right)$$ Back to $\theta$
$$A=2 \theta +\frac{2 \theta ^2}{3}+\frac{2 \theta ^3}{5}+\frac{2 \theta
   ^4}{7}+O\left(\theta ^5\right)$$ It just remains to multiply, axpand and simplify before deviding by $ \theta ^2$to finally obtain
$$f(\theta) =3+\frac{\theta }{5}+\frac{3 \theta ^2}{70}+O\left(\theta ^3\right)$$ which shows the limit and how it is approached. Moreover, it gives an approximation which could be very useful for other purposes.

For example, use $\theta =0.1$ (far way from $0$). The exact value is, in decimals, $f(0.1)=3.02044$ while the truncated series gives $3.02043$.

For the limit when $\theta\to 1^-$, I should let $\theta=1-x$ and work around $x=0$ (this is always easier). I let you doing the work to arrive at
$$f(\theta) =(24 \log (4)-30)+x (30 \log (4)-42)+x^2 \left(36 \log
   (4)-\frac{99}{2}\right)+O\left(x^3\right)$$ Jus replace $x$ by $1-\theta$.

Here again, try with $\theta=0.9$.  The exact value is, in decimals, $f(0.9)=3.23294$ while the truncated series gives $3.23401$.